# Check only if two nodes are within a given distance (path length) in a Graph

Tags: python, graph, nodes, distance, breadth-first-search

I am trying to implement a python function which checks if two given nodes (`start` and `goal`) are within a certain distance (let's say dist=4) in a Graph.

One crude way is to find the shortest path (using the [Breadth First Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) ) between the two nodes, and then check if the length of the shortest path is less (or equal) than the prescribed distance (dist = 4). But this obviously is not the best solution and has a lot of overhead. Starting from these two python functions, could you please direct me to how I could modify these functions to have such function?

As I mentioned, I am not interested in the found path per se. All our interest is in whether or not two nodes are **within** a prescribed distance from each other. A `YES` or `NO` return flag should suffice.

```
def bfs_paths(graph, start, goal):
    queue = [(start, [start])]
    while queue:
        (vertex, path) = queue.pop(0)
        for next in graph[vertex] - set(path):
            if next == goal:
                yield path + [next]
            else:
                queue.append((next, path + [next]))

def shortest_path(graph, start, goal):
    try:
        return next(bfs_paths(graph, start, goal))
    except StopIteration:
        return None
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to find the shortest distance between them. All you have to do is cut off your bfs after the desired `dist`. If you don't visit the goal node before the cutoff then the distance between start and goal is more than `dist`. Also you can use dfs in a similar manner. Cutoff the search when depth got bigger than `dist`. This search method is called Depth Limited Search.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response @Tempux. I totally understand your logic. I am a bit stuck with the implementation, though. I believe each `bfs_paths` call returns a path. How should I exactly modify it (along with shoretest_path) to stop when the path length is more than `dist`?